# Is any extra overhead to store non index field(JSON) as Object instead of text in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have two options to store JSON into Elasticsearch represent as object field(mentioned in first mapping ) and serialized and store as text(mentioned into second mapping). Is any extra overhead to store nonindex field as Object instead of text into Elasticsearch?

First Mapping:

```
{
 "properties": {
     "user_json": {
       "enabled": false,
        "type": "object"
   }
 }
```

Second Mapping:

```
{  "properties":
   {   
   "user_json": {
    "enabled": false,
    "type": "text"   
    } 
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `text` and `object` are two completely different types. If you expect to store serialized JSON data, you should avoid `text` and use `keyword` instead, since you're probably not going to search inside that data.

Comment: @Val Good idea. But there is a possibility for large JSON.   Is any advantage of storing  object vs keyword?

Comment: `enabled` can only be set on `object` fields. It's useful if you need to retrieve that JSON from the `_source`, but you will not be able to search on any of the nested fields. `keyword` only makes sense if you want to store that JSON as serialized JSON text. So it depends on your use case. See more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html)

Comment: I don't want search on this field only storing for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use the `object` type with `enabled` set to `false`.

Using `keyword` without the need to aggregate, sort or exact-match on that field doesn't really make sense and would be taking space in the inverted index for no obvious reason.

You'll still be able to retrieve the JSON object from the `_source`.